# Singly Linked List Time

Tags: c++, pointers, singly-linked-list

Given a Singly linked list that contains a pointer to the head, and one to the tail. Which would be the most time consuming?

- Inserting node at beginning
- Inserting node at the end
- Deleting node at the beginning
- Deleting node at the end

I think inserting node at the end because to do this we have to loop through the whole linked list, then insert the data of the node, then link the node correspondingly.

However with the research I've done deleting node at the end also seems to be a valid options, which would you say takes the most amount of time?

Comment: Deleting the node at the end will require identifying the previous node. For all other operations you have a pointer to the node to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

**Deleting node at the end** : Need to traverse all linked list because it requires to update second last node to update next pointer to NULL.

Comment: But.. Thinking aloud. 
Delting:
removeNode = currentNode;
removeNode->back->next = null;
delete removeNode;

insert:
newnode = new Node<>();
newNode->next = null;
node->next = newNode;

So that makes it the same amount of steps.

Comment: How do you have `removeNode->back` if it's a Single linked list? If accessing `back` is possible, then all operations would take same amount

Comment: If you are storing `next` and `back` pointers in node then this will become Doubly linked list which allows two way traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what it takes for each

**Inserting node at beginning**: Constant time

```
inserted.next = head
head = inserted
```

**Inserting node at the end**: Constant time

```
tail.next = inserted
tail = inserted
```

**Deleting node at the beginning**: Constant time

```
old_head = head
head = head.next
delete old_head
```

**Deleting node at the end**: linear time <-- most expensive

```
old_tail = tail
new_tail = head
while new_tail.next is not None:
    new_tail = new_tail.next
tail = new_tail
delete old_tail
```

Answer (score 1):

Analysing the complexity here.

Assuming the list structure is as below

node1-> node2-> node3-> node4-> node5

head--------------------------------------------tail

**Inserting node at the end** : tail-> next = newNode; O(1)

**Deleting node ate the end** : Don't have the prev pointer for tail (as it is singly linked list) so have to traverse the entire list to find secondlast node. O(n)

```
secondlast_node->next = Null;
free(tail);
tail = secondlast_node;
```

(The answer may change if you managed to construct the list differently)

If you have constructed the linked list as in the below example

node1<-node2<-node3<-node4<-node5

head---------------------------------------------------tail

Deleting node at the beginning becomes the most expensive operation

but in both the cases inserting node at the end is O(1) complexity

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where your pointer is.If its at the beginning, its going to be insertion and deletion at the last node.

Comment: (with a `head` and `tail` pointer, you have both a pointer to `head` and a pointer to `tail`)

Answer (score 0):

if you have two pointers which pointing to head and tail
1. inserting : both takes O(1)  as just modifying head and tail pointers.
2. Deleting:   head side deleting takes O(1)  time , however , tail needs  previous pointer which requires O(n) time complexity.

Assume: it is Single Linked List.
for DLL  all takes O(1)